# interrupt problem on PIC16f1823 - MPLab

Tags: pic, interrupts

I am using pic16f1823 and MPLab as IDE. I want to have simple interrupt on RA2 and turn on LED, when it come. I've wrote This code, but it doesn't work!

```
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON      // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Memory Code Protection (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Switchover (Internal/External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PLLEN = ON       // PLL Enable (4x PLL enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)
```

And for main app, we have :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main_10.h"



void interrupt tc_int(void)
{
    //if (INTCONbits.INTF == 1)
    if (INTCONbits.T0IF && INTCONbits.T0IE)    
    {
        LATCbits.LATC1 = 1;
        __delay_ms(1000);
        LATCbits.LATC1 = 0;
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }
    INTCONbits.INTF = 0;
}


/*
 * 
 */
void main (void)
{
    OSCCON = 0x76;//Very Important,this will command micro to use internal oscillator

    //prepare Interrupt on A2
    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1; //make interrupt port as input.
    OPTION_REGbits.INTEDG = 0; //make sense to falling edge.
    INTCONbits.INTE = 1;    //interrupt enable.
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; //Globally enable interrupts.
    INTCONbits.INTF = 0;    //make interrupt flag clear.




    //prepare output on PORTC.bit1
    LATCbits.LATC1 = 0; //initialization of portc.0
    TRISCbits.TRISC1 = 0; //make portc.0 as output.

    while(1)
    {

    }

}
```

And we have Proteus simulation like this:
[image]

where is the mistake?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this a complete schematic? MCLR seems to be enabled in your config, yet it is floating.

Comment: > where is the mistake? You didn't read the datasheet on how to turn that pin to GPIO.

Comment: Many thanks @glen_geek, for your comment! Yes! you are right! I changed the schematic; but i think this is not the main problem of lack of interrupt

Comment: I've read the datasheet @dannyf, and that was just a simple mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of effort, I solved my problem. thanks to @JohnBirckhead.
we encountered with two wrong bit set.

```
    1. TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 0

       //should be converted to:

       TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1

    2. INTCONbits.T0IF && INTCONbits.T0IE

       //should be converted to (in if statement in isr function):

        INTCONbits.INTF == 1 && INTCONbits.INTE == 1
       // because we are working with external interrupt.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting A2 as an output using TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 0;  should be 1.  Easy to remember: a zero looks like an "o" (output) and a 1 looks like an "I" (input).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, i changed TRISAbits.TRISA2 to 1, but interrupt is not working, yet

Comment: I edited my code, and correct that mistake

Comment: @paradisalprogrammer To clarify: Do you still have the problem, even after you incorporated these changes?

Comment: Yes! @pipe , when i press push button on PORTA.2, LED on PORTC.2 doesn't blink